# Classic ASP - Parsing xml with the specific format

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I would like to extract the columns and values for each group code from the below XML.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<MAIN-MENU>
    <GRPCODE1>
        <COLUMNS>ColA~ColB</COLUMNS>
        <VALUE1>Value11~Value12</VALUE1>
        <VALUE2>Value21~Value22</VALUE2>
    </GRPCODE1>
    <GRPCODE2>
        <COLUMNS>ColA~ColB~ColC</COLUMNS>
        <VALUE1>Value11~Value12~Value13</VALUE1>
        <VALUE2>Value21~Value22~Value23</VALUE2>
        <VALUE3>Value31~Value32~Value23</VALUE3>
    </GRPCODE2>
</MAIN-MENU>
```

```vb
Set objXMLResponse = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
objXMLResponse.Async = False
objXMLResponse.LoadXML(strXML)
If objXMLDoc.parseError.errorcode = 0 Then
    Dim node
    Dim groupNode
    'Iterate through each group code
    For Each groupNode in xml.selectSingleNode("/MAIN-MENU").childNodes
        Dim row
        Dim colArray, valueArray
        row = 0
        For Each node in groupNode.childNodes
            'Iterate through the columns and values
            Response.Write("<br>" & Server.HTMLEncode(node.xml) & "<br>")
            If row = 0 Then
                colArray = Split(node.xml, "~")
            Else
                valueArray = Split(node.xml, "~")
            End If
            'Processing code goes here
            row = row + 1
        Next
    Next
End If
```

I have the above code, but it does not iterate. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I am able to get the value for the given groupcode with the following code:
Set objGroupCode =objXMLResponse.SelectNodes("MAIN-MENU/GRPCODE1/COLUMNS") from the sample xml in the problem above.  But the same code does not work with the xml that I receive from the MicroService Call.  What could be wrong with the xml that I am receiving from the microservice?

Comment: If you are having problems with another xml than shown, you should [edit] and add that xml to your question. Please also add the above comment to your question.

Comment: When parsing XML with classic asp I've always found the easiest way to do it is to do an XSLT transformation.  If you can get your head around how XSL works then the asp/vbs code which does the transformation on the server side is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

I thank SearchAndResQ and John for your input. 
I have resolved the problem by the following code to access the column and value information.

```
Set objGroup1 = objXMLResponse.getElementsByTagName("GRPCODE1/COLUMNS")(0)
arrayColumns = Split(objGroup1.text, "~")
'Get the index from ArrayColumns for the needed columns
'Then Getting the values for the indexids from the values array.
Dim idx
For idx = 1 to 99
    strTag = "GRPCODE1/VALUE" & CStr(idx)
    Set objValue = objXMLResponse.getElementsByTagName(strTag)(0)
    If Len(objValue.text) = 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If
    arrayValueDetail = Split(objValue.text, "~")
    'process arrayValueDetail and store results
    set objValue = Nothing
Next
```